# BOTO throwing UnboundLocalError while doing get_bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, emr

I am trying to upload a big file of ~46Gb file to S3 from EMR using boto.
The code I wrote is

```
>>> import math, os
>>> import boto
>>> from filechunkio import FileChunkIO

# Connect to S3
>>> c = boto.connect_s3()
>>> b = c.get_bucket('mybucket')
```

This is throwing me the error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'region_name' referenced before assignment
```

You can find the entire stack of the same error in the following link:

https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2624

Can someone tell me what is the fix for this issue, please?

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? There's possibly an issue with your credentials - indent the boto methods in a `try` block and print any exception messages.

Comment: b = c.get_bucket('mybucket') is throwing the error. I haven't give in the credentials yet. The bucket I am accessing is a public bucket.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `boto.s3.connection.S3Connection`, which works perfectly.

This is my code, which might help you:

```
import os
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def connect_to_s3(access_key=ACCESS_KEY, secret_key=SECRET_KEY,
                  use_sigv4=False):
    kwargs = {
        'aws_access_key_id': access_key,
        'aws_secret_access_key': secret_key
    }
    if use_sigv4:
        os.environ['S3_USE_SIGV4'] = 'True'
        kwargs['host'] = 's3.amazonaws.com'
    else:
        os.environ['S3_USE_SIGV4'] = ''
    conn = S3Connection(**kwargs)
    try:
        yield conn
    finally:
        conn.close()
```

I'm using `boto==2.40.0`